Proving set function is countably additive
Let set $X=\{\frac{1}{2^n}: n\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
For any $A\subseteq X$, define
$$
v(A)=\sup
\bigg\{
\sum_{a\in F} a: F \text{ is a finite subset of } A
\bigg\}
$$
$P(X):=\{A:A\subseteq X\}$ is the power set of $X$. Show that $v: P(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a countably additive set function, i.e. for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $A_n\subseteq X$,
$$
\bigg[
\forall i,j\in \mathbb{N}, i\neq j, A_i\cap A_j = \emptyset 
\bigg] 
\implies 
v\bigg(\cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n
\bigg)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v(A_n) 
$$
where we force $\sup\{\emptyset\}=0$.
My attempt is shown below where I answer my own question. I am not sure if my proof is rigorous enough and even if it works, I may be overcomplicating things. Any comment or alternative solution is greatly appreciated.
note: this question seems to be a special case of the proposition in Proving set function is measure but my method seems to be different.

First show the following lemma:
Lemma. For any $F$ which is a finite subset of $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$, there exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ and some onto function $g:\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ such that $F=\bigcup_{k=1}^K (F\cap A_{g(k)})$.
Proof
For any $F$ which is a finite subset of $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$, there exists $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $|F|=K$ and
$$
    F=\{f_1,f_2,...f_K\}
$$
Since $F\subset \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$, for all $f\in F$, there exists $n$ such that $f\in A_n$. Thus, we can construct function $g$ with domain $\mathbb{N}=\{1,...,K\}\cup\{K+1,...\}$:
$$
g:\{1,...,K\}\cup\{K+1,...\} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} 
$$
such that

$f_k\in A_{g(k)} \text{ for all } k\in\{1,...,K\}$ AND
$g(\{K+1,K+2,...\})=\mathbb{N}\setminus g(\{1,...,K\})$

Thus, $g$ is onto: $g(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{N}$ by definition. Since $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for all $i\neq j$, $F$ is a subset of some (finite) disjoint union: $F\subset  \bigcup_{k=1}^K A_{g(k)}$. Furthermore,
$$
F\subset  \bigcup_{k=1}^K A_{g(k)}\implies F=F\cap (\bigcup_{k=1}^K A_{g(k)})= \bigcup_{k=1}^K (F\cap A_{g(k)})
$$
PROOF
now I prove that
$$v:P(X)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$ is countably additive:
By definition:
$v(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n)=\sup\{\sum_{a\in F} a : F \text{ is a finite subset of } \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n\}$
$(i)=\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in \cup_{k=1}^{K} (F\cap A_{g(k)} )} a \bigg) :  F \text{ is a finite subset of } \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n
\bigg\}$
$(ii)=\sup
\bigg\{
\sum_{k=1}^{K} \bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_{g(k)}} a \bigg) :  F ...
\bigg\}$
$(iii)=\sum_{k=1}^{K}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_{g(k)}} a \bigg) :  F ...
\bigg\}$
$(iv)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_n} a \bigg) :  F ...
\bigg\}$
$(v)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_n} a \bigg) :  F\cap A_n \text{ is a finite subset of } A_n
\bigg\}$
$ (vi)=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in B} a \bigg) :  B \text{ is a finite subset of } A_n
\bigg\}$
$= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} v(A_n)$ QED.
explanation for steps $(i)-(vi)$. some obvious ones omitted

$(ii)$: $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset, i\neq j$ implies $A_{g(i)} \cap A_{g(j)} = \emptyset, i\neq j$. Proof is tedious so omitted.
$(iii)$: uses $\sup(A+B)=\sup(A)+\sup(B)$ where $A,B$ non-empty and bounded! bounded because of $\frac{1}{2^n}\rightarrow 1<\infty$ and non-emptyset is not needed since even if empty, $\sup\emptyset$ is forced to be $0$. To clarify, the set $A+B:= \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\}$, and use mathematical induction.
$(iv)$:

For all $k\in\{K+1,K+2...\}$, $F\cap A_{g(k)}=\emptyset$ since $A_i\cap A_j=\emptyset$ for $i\neq j$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_{g(k)}} a \bigg) : F \text{ is a finite subset of } \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n
\bigg\} \\
=
\sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty}
\sup \emptyset
= \infty \times 0 =0
\end{aligned} 
$$
so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{K}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_{g(k)}} a \bigg) :  F \text{ is a finite subset of } \cup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n
\bigg\} \\
= \sum_{k=1}^{K}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_{g(k)}} a \bigg) : ...
\bigg\} 
+
\sum_{k=K+1}^{\infty}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_{g(k)}} a \bigg) : ...
\bigg\} 
\\
=
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
\sup
\bigg\{
\bigg(
\sum_{a\in F\cap A_n} a \bigg) :  F \text{ is a finite subset of } \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n
\bigg\}
\end{aligned}
$$
